# In python (2.7) when using 'with open', do I need a 'finally close' block in case of error thrown (see example)

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, with-statement, try-catch-finally

When using 'with open' if an exception occurs do I need a finally block to ensure the file is closed.
e.g.

```
try:
    with open(self.some_path, "r") as a_file:
        self.yaml_contents = yaml.load(a_file.read())
except IOError as ex:
    logger.error("Failed to open (or load) settings file '{}' because '{}'".format(self.some_path,ex.strerror))
    raise
```

If open() throws, assuming it did actually open the file, will it be closed or do I need to close it?
Also if yaml.load() throws, then will the with open still complete i.e. close() the file?

```
try:
    with open(self.some_path, "r") as a_file:
        self.yaml_contents = yaml.load(a_file.read())
except IOError as ex:
    logger.error("Failed to open (or load) settings file {} because {}".format(self.some_path,ex.strerror))
    raise
finally:
    a_file.close()
```

But now a_file is not in scope, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with open(filepath, mode) as a_file` statement keeps the file open only inside of that segment - when it "exits" the segment there is no need for `a_file.close()`, regardless of where an exception is thrown - in `open()` or in `yaml.load(...)`.